# autolaunch of application in linux

Tags: linux, embedded

i have linux os on my leopard target board with tms320dm368 processor. its a raw board with only kernel and rfs. there is no linux distribution (ubuntu,fedora,red hat etc) on the target board.
I created the script file as following

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "my application is here"
./helloworld  # helloworld is our application
```

1. after creating the script file i copied it in `init.d`
2. I gave the command `chmod +x /etc/init.d/vcc_app` (`vcc_app` is the name of script which I have created)
3. Then I gave the command `ln -s /etc/init.d/vcc_app /etc/rc.d/vcc_app` (`rc.d` is the run level directory)

But when i reboot the board my application is not executed automatically. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Since you say 'it is a raw board with only kernel': Do you have 'sh'? (sorry, I don't know what 'rfs' means)

Answer (score 0):

You should put your script in `/etc/rcX.d/vcc_app` , change X for the init level where you want to execute, if you want to run it on init 5 then the script should be placed at:

```
/etc/rc5.d/vcc_app
```

For more information of init level, [check this link](http://www.krishnababug.com/2009/04/what-are-init-0-init-1-init-2-init-3.html)

Also in some distribution you can add a command to launch your script at `/etc/rc.local`
or `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, check which files exists and add the command.

Comment: but if i copy my script file vcc_app inside /etc/rcx.d then there is no need to run ln -s /etc/init.d/vcc_app /etc/rc.d/vcc_app (rc.d is the run level directory) command....because this command is to create symbolic link between /etc/init.d to /etc/rc.d....

Comment: @Skatox : I think there is no run-level directories (rc1.d....rc5.d) as well as rc.local present in the board. All he/she has is rc.d.
I think creating a new rc.local file would be a good idea.

Comment: @user1415119 Yes, you're right. Did you created a rc.local file ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be very interesting to know what you actually have on your board - you claim you do not have a distribution but yet you use something (/etc/init.d) that is only available in distrubutions of a kind.

So assuming you really don't use a distribution, it means you do not have a shell, you do not have an init system.

If you only need to run a single application, there's no need for any shell or such - just make your application statically linked and put it in your rootfs as /sbin/init, /etc/init, /bin/init. See [linux kernel main.c init_post()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.4/init/main.c%20%20main.c%3ainit_post%28%29).

Otherwise if you have more than one application, you need an init system.
An easy one is [uxlaunch](http://meego.gitorious.org/meego-os-base/uxlaunch), other options include [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd) or [busybox init](http://www.busybox.net/).
Even with busybox init, you still don't necessarily need a shell on your system.

Several devices in the market are running Linux without a shell, including many television sets.

Comment: Statically linked means that you add `-static` to the command line of the linker. It will then add in all libraries into your binary. You can easily verify this by running `ldd` on the binary: it will not list any libraries. Of course, if you are cross-compiling, use the cross-version of ldd.